# POSTGRESQL - SELECT withing update and condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dml

I need to update a PSQL table with two fields. The first field need to copy a field from the table, and the other field need to be a string.

I don't know how I can did it. Here is an example of what I want to do :

If a record have the column '`custom_t4`' empty and the column '`parent_id`' equal to 0 , replace the value with '`Dossier_client`' value.
If a record have the column '`custom_t15`' empty, replace it with '`folder_id`' value

Here is an exemple : 
If I have this :

```
╔═══════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╤════════════╗
║ folder_id │ parent_id │ custom_t4 │ custom_t15 ║
╠═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╣
║ 123456    │ 0         │           │            ║
╚═══════════╧═══════════╧═══════════╧════════════╝
```

I need to have something like this :

```
╔═══════════╤═══════════╤════════════════╤════════════╗
║ folder_id │ parent_id │ custom_t4      │ custom_t15 ║
╠═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════════╪════════════╣
║ 123456    │ 0         │ Dossier_client │ 123456     ║
╚═══════════╧═══════════╧════════════════╧════════════╝
```

For now I try this query, only for the 'custom_t4' field. It's working, but I don't know how to do for custom_t15 :

```
UPDATE folders SET custom_t4 = 'Dossier_client' WHERE parent_id = 0;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide: create table statement, sample data and if possible also the query you've tried so far.

Comment: post Updated :)

Comment: `UPDATE folders SET custom_t5 = folder_id::text WHERE custom_t5 is null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this update using  `CASE` statement. I assume both `custom_t15` and `folder_id` are of same type or else you may need to cast (`::`) them appropriately.

```
UPDATE folders
SET custom_t4 = CASE 
        WHEN custom_t4 IS NULL
            AND parent_id = 0
            THEN 'Dossier_client'
        ELSE custom_t4
        END
    ,custom_t15 = COALESCE(custom_t15, folder_id)
  -- DON'T forget a valid where clause;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b40b/1)

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! :)